# Como pintar barras desplazadas en Charts de ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy probando en un chart de asp.net como conseguir pintar barras en vez de la manera tradicional:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De esta manera si el punto a pintar es el 1, pinta a la izquierda y la derecha de dicho punto.
Pero lo que yo necesito, es que si el punto a pintar es 1, solamente pinte hacia la izquierda o la derecha ( a elegir) desde un punto al siguiente tal y como se muestra en la imagen de abajo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo maximo que he logrado es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante el siguiente codigo:

```
 Chart1.Series.Clear();

    int[,] horas = new int[,] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 6, 0 }, { 7, 0 }, { 8, 1 }, { 9, 1 } };
    Chart1.DataSource = horas;
    var series1 = new Series
    {
        Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn,
    };
    series1["PixelPointWidth"] = "1";

    int[,] horas1 = new int[,] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 6, 0 }, { 7, 0 }, { 8, 1 }, { 9, 1 } };
    var series2 = new Series
    {
        Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn
    };
    series2["PixelPointWidth"] = "110";

    for (int i = 0; i < horas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        series1.Points.AddXY(horas[i, 0], horas[i, 1]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < horas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        series2.Points.AddXY(horas1[i, 0], horas1[i, 1]);
    }

    int b = 0;
    foreach (var label in Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels)
    {
        label.Text = b.ToString();
        b++;
    }

    Chart1.Series.Add(series1);
    Chart1.Series.Add(series2);

    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    Chart1.DataBind();
```

Si embargo esta solucion no es optima porque me exige poner al menos un pixel en el lado que no me interesa.

Basicamente lo que necesito es saber si existe la posibilidad de desplazar en el eje X los valores a pintar, de tal forma que si el punto a pintar es el 1 y le pongo un desplazamiento a la derecha de 55px me lo pintaria de manera correcta.

P.D: Cualquier otra solucion que consiga el resultado deseado me vale.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.